# RESTful WCF Service errors when hosted on HTTPS only

Tags: vb.net, rest, wcf

A few years ago I followed this [RESTful WCF Services with No svc file and No config](https://stevemichelotti.com/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config/) very useful article on setting up RESTful WCF with out using svc files and worked like a dream.  But recently I've had to move the site over to HTTPS (still keeping the HTTP for testing) and all worked fine, until I removed the binding for the HTTP site and I get an error message that points back to this entry in the web.config:

```
<webHttpEndpoint>
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
</webHttpEndpoint>
```

Removing the entry fixes the error, but it stops the auto generated help page that this setting provides.

Here is a brief snippet of the 2 errors that is thrown:

*Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/myService' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].*

*Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MyService' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: An endpoint reference cycle was detected in your configuration. The following reference cycle must be removed: webHttpEndpoint/, webHttpEndpoint/. (...\web.config line 222). ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An endpoint reference cycle was detected in your configuration. The following reference cycle must be removed: webHttpEndpoint/, webHttpEndpoint/. (...\web.config line 222)*

Hoping someone has seen and fixed this problem before.

Comment: Can you share ...\web.config line 222 where error is coming `The following reference cycle must be removed: webHttpEndpoint/, webHttpEndpoint/`. Also what is binding used ?

Comment: This is what is at line 222: <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false">

Comment: and I think I've found the issue, I had no binding entry, so by adding <security mode="Transport" /> does seem to fix it, although I need to get a full set of tests done

Comment: OK , that is great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this, so I needed a binding, the updated web.config is like this:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />                 
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Comment: Will do, but it won't let me do that for 2 days, so will come back. :-)